# Laravel api routes doesn't works - 404

Tags: laravel, routes, http-status-code-404

I try to use API routing but my routes don't work.

When I try to login with http://xxxxxxx/api/v1/auth/login

The server sends me a 404 error. Do you have an idea?

```
// Auth Endpoints
Route::group([
'middleware' => 'cors',
'prefix' => 'v1/auth'
], function ($router) {
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LogoutController@logout');
Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
Route::post('forgot-password', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@email');
Route::post('password-reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
});

// Resource Endpoints
Route::group([
'middleware' => 'cors',
'prefix' => 'v1'
], function ($router) {
Route::apiResource('todo', 'TodoController');
});
```

> // Not Found Route::fallback(function(){
> return response()->json(['message' => 'Resource not found.'], 404); });```

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming this is in the `routes/api.php` file. If you declared all of this in the web routes file then there won't be any `api` prefixing it.

Check if your routes actually exist by running `php artisan r:l` in the console.

Comment: These are the api routes in api files and they exists in php artisan r:l

Comment: Are you using auth for some of the routes? IIRC the api auth requires a 60 character string to be passed as a token by default.

Answer (score 1):

You run only "php artisan route:clear"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: By the way in my project on docker was RUN "php artisan route:clear" and after RUN "php artisan optimize" - this brocken my API project

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't sent a POST data. If you send a Url, you only send a GET. If you want to send POST verb, you can use a software like Postman to sent an URL http://xxxxxxx/api/v1/auth/login + POST data at the same time.

Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login'); <- POST, not found ... 404

Comment: Yes of course, but this error is triggered when I click on the login button of my react component. I send a post request.

Comment: _ You app is routing Route fallback -> 404
_ Check if Controller  Auth\LoginController is OK
_ Check if Method login in Auth\LoginController is Ok
_ Check if Middleware           \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class is working well in app\HTTP\Kernel.php
_ Maybe is some code in Middleware that don't allows you route. it's because is after to routing.  
_

Comment: I've tried to add a get test route in API and the result is the same: 404

Comment: Are your routes cached? Try `php artisan route:clear`

Answer (score 0):

Just as a future note to myself and in case it helps someone else, I was getting  this error because I had a parameterized route that was taking precedence over another route with no parameters, but same signature, like this:

```
Route::prefix('post')->group(function () {
   Route::get('/', [PostController::class, 'index']);
   Route::get('/{post}', [PostController::class, 'show']);
   Route::get('/primary', [PostController::class, 'primary']);
   Route::get('/active3', [PostController::class, 'active3']);
   Route::get('/all', [PostController::class, 'index']);
});
```

Now whenever I tried to access `/post/primary`, it would return 404, even though the route is there and was even listing in `php artisan route:list` command results.

All of sudden it occurred to me that Laravel was search for a matching route in the order in which I have specified them, so `post/{post}` is a perfect match for `post/primary` (the word `primary` matches the parameter `{post}`) and therefore it goes to `show` function, which then fails because there is no `Post` with the id `primary` in the table and returns 404 (this is a Laravel feature called type-hinting).

The solution is to either move your parameterized route below the non-parameterized routes, so that those routes take precedence, or to introduce a `where` filter in your parameterized route, so that it matches numbers only, like this:

```
Route::get('/{post}', [PostController::class, 'show'])->whereNumber('poll');
```

Answer (score -1):

This could be due to php's *opcache* caching the routes files.

This happened to me and was difficult to debug because:

When I did `php artisan route:list` through the cli, it would show the correct information (as the php cli does not share opcache pool with php-fpm)

When traffic came through php-fpm, it would use old opcache.

The opcache was not cleared in my case, as I do zero downtime deployments using symlinks.

My solution was to have my deploy script restart php-fpm service.